# Best way for favorite list in Android?

Tags: android, android-memory, android-savedstate

I want use Favorite list feature in my application, but i don't know which one is the best method, **Save in SQLiteDataBase** or **SharedPreference**.Which is the best way to manage Memory?
Please explain the reason for choosing the better i know.

Thanks all <3

Comment: Uh... Manage what? Do you need a database or just some temporary local storage?

Comment: @Shark,sorry manage Memory and update above post! no i want just save user favorite list and show this list in other activity. for this job, DataBase is optimized or Preferences?

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences`, it literally requires at least 10 times less code. A few lines actually.

Comment: @Shark, thanks my dear friend for this help <3

Comment: Flagging this to be closed as "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions"

Comment: @Shark, please add your help to my answer and i accept it for help another people.

Comment: @EdGeorge - while that is true, I understand the purpose of the question a bit differently. I understand it as "should I use a CD or a DVD for a few mp3 songs" and the obvious answer is - "use a CD, you waste less space" when the real, non-opinionated answer is "use whatever you can play in your car". No need to create a whole database to just save a single `ArrayList` IMHO. (yes, the imho was intentional)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Database but decide which one ok for you. You can use [ActiveAndroid](http://www.activeandroid.com/) this very good libray to store data in SQLite. This very simple to add project and implement it. ActiveAndroid is an ORM for Android. It’s an abstraction over SQLite which allows you to communicate with a database on a device without writing SQL statements. An Object that extends ActiveAndroid Model can be saved to the data.

For example from api reference:

```
Item item = new Item();
item.category = restaurants;
item.name = "Outback Steakhouse";
item.save();
```

you can save data in Sqlite like this. And

```
public static Item getRandom(Category category) {
    return new Select()
        .from(Item.class)
        .where("Category = ?", category.getId())
        .orderBy("RANDOM()")
        .executeSingle();
}
```

retrive data like this example. I use Github example in this post. You can find extended explanation in [ActiveAndroid Github](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid)